# Calculating True Course, Magnetic Heading and Compass Heading when Wind, True Heading, Magnetic Course and Deviation is known

Tags: navigation, magnetic-compass

I came across another exercise while studying for my PPL(A) exam where I would need some help with some calculations.

The question sounds like this:

> Given: WCA: -012°; TH: 125°; MC: 139°; DEV: 002°E What are: TC, MH und
> CH?
>
> a.) TC: 113°  MH: 127°  CH: 129°
>  b.) TC: 137°  MH: 127°  CH: 125°
> <--- this is the correct answer
>  c.) TC: 137°  MH: 139°  CH:
> 125°
>  d.) TC: 113°  MH: 139°  CH: 129°

I think for calculating the True Course (TC) I need to subtract the Deviation Angle (DEV)
from the Magnetic Course (MC): TC = 139° - 2° = 137°. Why subtracting, well based on "West is Best, East is Least" principle... I hope :)

For the Magnetic Heading (MH) I need to subtract the Wind Correction Angle (WCA) from the Magnetic Course (MC): MH = 139° - 12° = 127°. Why subtracting, well because the exercise tells me it's from an -012° angle... I hope :)

But how do I get now the Compass Heading (CH)?
Are actually any of my assumption correct?

Later Edit:

OK, so i notice now after reading more that my assumption for TC is a false positive. I think, normally TH = TC + WCA, so in my case 125 = TC + -12. So TC must be 137 in order for TH to be 125°

Based on the same assumption, if my Magnetic Course (MC) is 139°, applying the WCA would mean that my Magnetic Heading (MH) must be 127°.

Now subtracting the Deviation angle from the MH, would mean the CH is 125°...